# Spring Boot: Configuring subdomain, hostname and port through app properties

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

My Spring Boot app will have 4 different environments:

- Local; running locally on my machine
- Dev
- UAT
- Prod

When a new user registers for my app, the backend sends them an email to verify their address/account. In this email there will be a link; the user clicks the link which verifies them in the database and allows them to now login and use the app.

These links of course have to have the environment built into them:

- Locally, the link might be `http://localhost:9200/v1/data/accounts/verify?vt=12345`
- In dev the link might be: `http://dev.myapp.example.com/v1/data/accounts/verify?vt=12345`
- In UAT the link might be: `http://uat.myapp.example.com/v1/data/accounts/verify?vt=12345`
- In Prod the link might be: `http://myapp.example.com/v1/data/accounts/verify?vt=12345`

In all three environments, the hostname + port are different. Locally I specify `localhost:9200` (both localhost + port). Non-locally I don't need to specify port because the app will be running on nodes behind a load balancer. In production I don't need an environment-specific subdomain like `dev` or `uat`.

In order for my emails to work correctly in all 4 environments, I need to set an environment variable that is then used by my email generator to generate links correctly.

I *could* use something homegrown, such as a custom property in `application.properties` like `emailDomain`, and set the property different in each environment's properties file.

But I feel like the smart folks that make up the Spring Boot community have probably already solved this problem for me...have they? Is there already a Spring Boot app property I can set that will take care of all this for me?

Comment: you define specify define properties file for different domains. and let spring boot pick one based on the profile with which you start your application

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran (+1) however I disagree with that approach (baking environment logic into config files). IMHO properly-externalized config files are completely environment-agnostic-and-unaware. You let configuration management set environment-specific properties that are available to the app at startup, not some awkward "if(env == dev) { host = "dev.example.com"} else if(env == uat)..." logic.

Comment: Basically, you should be able to stand up a new environment, say, "demo", without having to modify code!

Comment: If you want functioanlity like that, then you should look into spring cloud config server. Even then you will have to restart your application(without which you cannot tell spring boot which profile you want to start with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, I read that your main concern is being able to update the property without having to modify your .JAR/.WAR or changing some code.

This is possible since you can externalize your Spring boot configuration. If you check the [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) docs, you can see that it looks for properties within:

> 10. OS environment variables.
>
> ...
>
> 12. Profile-specific application properties **outside of your packaged jar** (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants)
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants)
> 14. Application properties **outside of your packaged jar**
>       (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).

So, ideally, you can put an `application.properties` file next to your JAR, and update the properties in that file depending on the environment you run on.